# Conditionally trigger a full page postback from a link button inside an update panel

Tags: asp.net

How do I conditionally trigger a full page postback from a link button inside of an update panel?

I have a custom control that contains its own updatepanel with a link button nested inside of  it. When the link button is pressed I want its event handler to have the option of either letting the control update as normal or doing a full postback on the page.

**Here is the control hierarchy:**

```
Page
  Custom Control
    UpdatePanel
      LinkButton
```

**Event handler Pseudo code:**

```
LinkButton Click Handler Begin
    If is a partial post back AND a full postback is needed
        Page.DoFullPostback 
    End If
End Handler
```

**Note:** I aways need the partial postback to happen. I was considering injecting a `__DoPostback` in the controls markup but this seems hacky to me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the VB, so my example source will be written in C#:

```
protected void btnLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isAsync = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack;
    bool postBackIsNeeded = true;

    if (isAsync && postBackIsNeeded)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnClick);
        string postback = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(
            btnClick, 
            string.Empty
        );
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            btnClick, 
            btnClick.GetType(), 
            "postback", 
            postback, 
            true
       );
}
```

}

The main idea is to change the type of postback of your `LinkButton` control. If neccessary it should be changed to full postback instead of partial during the async postback event. Right after this, another postback script should be generated and it should be executed as soon as the page will be returned to client.

And the last thing - use loop detection condition (`if (isAsync && postBackIsNeeded)` in my case) otherwise postback will be infinite.

Comment: I needed this for a problem I had. I am dynamically generating controls in Page_Load based on ViewState objects. However, the viewstate objects are updated/modified in a button click event handler. According to the page life-cycle the button_click event handler executes after the button_click post-back, so my viewstate is essentially being updated after the page_load where it is used. I used this code in my button_click to cause another postback which causes page_load to execute again. Also I put my viewstate modification code within the if statement. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Isn't there a way to render the whole page from inside the asynchronous postback without posting back a second time? This seems to happen to a lot of people unwantedly, so I hoped there's a way to trigger that behavior dynamically, too.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to create a hidden button somewhere on your page, outside of any UpdatePanels. When you need to do a full postback, use JavaScript to either click the button or issue __doPostback() to it. You can achieve a partial postpack programmatically in JavaScript by calling __doPostback() on an UpdatePanel itself, or to a button inside one.